# Why apps with CefSharp WPF pluggable module stop unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

We are developing a plug-in WPF module. It consists of tabs inside each is used <cef: ChromiumWebBrowser Name = "nameNNN" ....

Everything works fine, but sometimes the application crashes unexpectedly. In win app logs

System.IO.IOException: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedView.CreateView(SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle memMappedFileHandle, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, Int64 offset, Int64 size)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor(Int64 offset, Int64 size, MemoryMappedFileAccess access)
at CefSharp.Wpf.Rendering.InteropBitmapRenderHandler.CreateOrUpdateBitmap(Boolean isPopup, Rect dirtyRect, IntPtr buffer, Int32 width, Int32 height, Image image, Size& currentSize, MemoryMappedFile& mappedFile, MemoryMappedViewAccessor& viewAccessor)
at CefSharp.Wpf.Rendering.AbstractRenderHandler.OnPaint(Boolean isPopup, Rect dirtyRect, IntPtr buffer, Int32 width, Int32 height, Image image)
at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.OnPaint(Boolean isPopup, Rect dirtyRect, IntPtr buffer, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.CefSharp.Internals.IRenderWebBrowser.OnPaint(PaintElementType type, Rect dirtyRect, IntPtr buffer, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at CefSharp.Internals.RenderClientAdapter.OnPaint(RenderClientAdapter* , scoped_refptr* browser, cef_paint_element_type_t type, vector<CefRect,std::allocator >* dirtyRects, Void* buffer, Int32 width, Int32 height)

In Cef debug.log

INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "[****] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http:", source: http://****jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js (9)
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"FFmpegDemuxer: no supported streams"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(35)] MediaEvent: {"pipeline_error":14}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"FFmpegDemuxer: no supported streams"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(35)] MediaEvent: {"pipeline_error":14}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"FFmpegDemuxer: no supported streams"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(35)] MediaEvent: {"pipeline_error":14}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"{"causes":[{"causes":[],"data":{},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decrypting_video_decoder.cc","line":53}],"status_code":264,"status_message":""}],"data":{"Decoder name":"DecryptingVideoDecoder"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decoder_selector.cc","line":172}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"{"causes":[{"causes":[],"data":{},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/vpx_video_decoder.cc","line":135}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}],"data":{"Decoder name":"VpxVideoDecoder"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decoder_selector.cc","line":172}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"{"causes":[{"causes":[],"data":{"codec":"vp8"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/dav1d_video_decoder.cc","line":165}],"status_code":260,"status_message":""}],"data":{"Decoder name":"Dav1dVideoDecoder"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decoder_selector.cc","line":172}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"{"causes":[{"causes":[],"data":{},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decrypting_video_decoder.cc","line":53}],"status_code":264,"status_message":""}],"data":{"Decoder name":"DecryptingVideoDecoder"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decoder_selector.cc","line":172}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"{"causes":[{"causes":[],"data":{},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decrypting_video_decoder.cc","line":53}],"status_code":264,"status_message":""}],"data":{"Decoder name":"DecryptingVideoDecoder"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decoder_selector.cc","line":172}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"{"causes":[{"causes":[],"data":{},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/vpx_video_decoder.cc","line":135}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}],"data":{"Decoder name":"VpxVideoDecoder"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decoder_selector.cc","line":172}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}"}
ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"{"causes":[{"causes":[],"data":{"codec":"vp8"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/dav1d_video_decoder.cc","line":165}],"status_code":260,"status_message":""}],"data":{"Decoder name":"Dav1dVideoDecoder"},"stack":[{"file":"../../media/filters/decoder_selector.cc","line":172}],"status_code":265,"status_message":""}"}

Additional info:

- Some of url used long polling request
- OS:          Windows 10 (64 bit)
- CefSharp:    84.4.10.0
- .NET:        4.0.30319

How to fix it ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Your application has run out of memory. Are you targeting x86 or x64 or AnyCpu?

Comment: CefSharp WPF we are targeting x86. Destination application is 32 bit. Destination computers are 64bit. Our monitoring tools did not fix memory problems, how can we confirm, make sure that the application is out of memory ?

Comment: The exception is pretty clear, the process is out of memory. A 32bit process by default can only access 2gb. Ideally you should target x64, if you absolutely have target x86 then make sure your application is large address aware. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#win32-out-of-memory

Comment: You might find https://www.nuget.org/packages/LargeAddressAware/ useful

Comment: Thanks for answers ! We will follow your advice in the next 2-3 days and inform about the results.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#offscreen-rendering-osr for background on how the WPF version renders. If you still have problems and have confirmed your application doesn't have any memory leaks of it's own then you might need to switch to the WinForms version hosted in a WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: After a series of tests, we localized the bug. The  render process  CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe sometime crashes. So we override IRequestHandler.OnRenderProcessTerminated and force reload the browser ...chromiumWebBrowser.Reload (true)... Now we are monitoring whether this will be enough. It is not clear what is written in debug. log. Could you tell me where to find a description or guide to it ?

Comment: There's no guide, you need to look at the chromium source and figure it out.

Comment: An out of memory exception in your main process is going to be unrelated to a subprocess crash. Version 84 is now outdated,  you should upgrade to version 85 as there was a major vulnerability found in Chromium see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/security/advisories/GHSA-pv36-h7jh-qm62

Comment: Accepted. We have upgraded the version of CefSharp in our build to 85.3.130. We continue testing. Thanks

Comment: Everything works correctly after the upgrade. The issue is closed. Thank you so much for your help !